# How does JWT Work in Smooch iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, jwt, smooch

I am playing with Smooch SDK. My question is about how does JWT Work in Smooch iOS ?

Currently I have 1 app, and if I want to use Smooch based on the user id , (ex. 1 app has 50 users to chat with it), do we need to generate 50 JWT or 1 JWT only?

```
    [Smooch login:self.smoochUserId jwt:@"WHAT IS THIS"];
```

Thank you

Comment: This issue might address some of your questions regarding JWTs, and includes external links to additional documentation https://github.com/smooch/smooch-ios/issues/168

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically in older versions of `Smooch` there is no feature like a user can not access the same conversation from multiple devices.

ie., If one user logged in one device and when second user logged in same device then

- Second user can see first user chats and
- Second user can not see his older chats if he had logged in with another device previously.

To overcome this problem `Smooch` introduces new method which you noted above with JWT (JSON web token). You can read more about that [Here](https://docs.smooch.io/guide/authenticating-users/).

```
do we need to generate 50 JWT or 1 JWT only?
```

You need to generate JWT [server side](https://docs.smooch.io/guide/authenticating-users/) for each user based on their userId (from your database).

If you are decided to go like this you need to create that JWT token with logged in userid and assign that token to `Smooch` via

```
[Smooch login:@"user-id" jwt:@"jwt" completionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error, NSDictionary * _Nullable userInfo) {
    // Your code after login is complete
}];
```

This is bit hard to do. There is another way to do it.

Find the sample node.js code from the link1 which I have submitted and give it to your backend server. And ask them to create for each user so that you can get that JWT token with the user model(Which you will get after success login).
Add that directly to `Smooch`.

Note: If you don't care about user existing chat details you can use `Smooch` without adding jwt token like this

```
[Smooch initWithSettings:[SKTSettings settingsWithAppId:@"Your App token(Get it from Smooch dashboard)"] completionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error, NSDictionary * _Nullable userInfo) {}
[[SKTUser currentUser] addProperties:@{@"Company":[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"company"],@"UserId":[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"empid"]}];
[Smooch show];
```

Comment: Please do not sign JWTs on your client device in Swift or Objective-C. Doing so implies distributing your app secret key with your mobile application, essentially granting all of your users access to your entire Smooch app (including integrations, webhooks, conversation history and profile information of every user, etc.). JWTs should be signed on your server and passed down to the client device.

Comment: ^While we're at it to reduce confusion, I've gone ahead and edited this answer, removing the suggestion to use an Obj-C JWT library.

Comment: @michaels  the problem is that smooch user is created when mobile send 1st message to Smooch. At that time, back end knows nothing about the new smooch user, so back-end cannot generate anyway.
may i know how to pass it correctly ? Or the sample node.js code is one of the way ?

Comment: @Abadi if your app having login process then must and should you backend server saving those credentials in DB. By default when they registered with your app your backend can generate jwt token.

Comment: Okay i got it.. i talked w my back end, they thought smooch user id is coming from smooch not from us.. thanks @Himanth

Comment: both @michaels and himant is helping me, so i will tick himanth answer as the solution bcs michaels answer is in the comment section :)